Is there a way to #include contents of Raw string without the delimiters?
I'm writing a thing for Arduino. The piece for the webpage currently has:
  const char index_html[] = 
#include "index.html.h"
  ;

where index.html.h contains:
R"MaRkEr(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>)MaRkEr"

It works correctly, but is unpleasant to debug/write as I can't just preview the contents of the file in a browser, and uploading every change to the microcontroller takes a lot of time. The .h extension is a silly Arduino requirement of little consequence, as I can create a link with proper extension, but I'm quite unhappy with the markers of raw string as they prevent the browser from seeing the file as HTML.
Obviously written verbatim, the markers make the string contain the #include statement instead of its contents. I tried to #define the open/close pieces, #include them from other files, nothing works.
Is there a way to do it? Maybe something connected with stringification of macro value or similar way to make the preprocessor first do the #include and then insert/substitute the markers?

C23 has #embed.  May be available for C++ use, depending on your compiler.

There is also proposal P1040R6 for adding std::embed to C++.
